# What's the best method to implement multiplayer on a Unity Billiard game?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'm making an online billiard game. I've finished all the mechanics for single player, online account system,  online inventory system etc. Everything's fine but I've gotten to the hardest part now, the multiplayer. I tried syncing the position of each ball every frame but the movement wasn't smooth at all, the balls would move back and forth and it looked "bad" in general. Does anyone have any solution for this ? How do other billiard games like the one in Miniclip do it, I'm honestly stuck here and frustrated as it took me a while to learn Photon networking then to find out it's not that good at handling the physics synchronization.

Would uNet be a better choice here ?

I appreciate any help you give me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with PUN already: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15802

You can try to play with synchronization settings or implement custom OnPhotonSerializeView (see DemoSynchronization in PUN package). Make sure that physic simulation disabled on synchronized clients. See DemoBoxes for physics simulation sample.

Or, if balls can move along lines only, do not send all positions every frame. Send positions and velocities only when balls colliding and do simple velocity simulation between. This can work even with more comprehensive physics but general rule is the same: synchronize it at key points. Of course this is not as simple as automatic synchronization.

Also note that classic billiard is turnbased game and you do not have all the complexity of players interaction. In worst case you can 'record' simulation on current player client and 'playback' it on others.

Comment: Hey, I tried syncing the balls' velocity, position and angular velocity but still, the results aren't the same, they differ from one client to the other. Any help ?

Comment: What about physics implementation used in DemoBoxes? It does not work for you for some reason?